# RoR rspec with field auto increment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Rails 6
Database PostgresSQL

File migration:

```rb
class CreateCategoriesCodeSequence < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE SEQUENCE categories_code_seq;
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      DROP SEQUENCE categories_code_seq CASCADE;
    SQL
  end
end
```

```rb
class AssignSequenceToTableCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      ALERT SEQUENCE categories_code_seq OWNED by categories.code;
      ALERT TABLE categories ALTER COLUMN code SET DEFAULT nextval('categories_code_seq');
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      ALERT SEQUENCE categories_code_seq OWNED by NONE;
    SQL
  end
end
```

File FactoryBot:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :category do
    sequence(:code) { |number| number }
    name { SecureRandom.hex(3) }
  end
end
```

File rspec:

```rb
...
let_it_be(:category) { FactoryBot.create(:category) }
let_it_be(:category_1) { FactoryBot.create(:category) }

describe 'POST #create' do
  subject do
   post_api '/api/v1/categories', params
   response
  end

  let(:params) do
    {
      name: 'cate_1'
    }
  end

  context 'Test create' do
    it {
      expect(subject).to have_http_status(:ok)
    }
  end
end
```

Controller categories call this function to create new record

```rb
  def create!(form)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      Category.create!(from)
    end
  end
```

This is result
[image]

When I add `rescue` in function `create!`, I see error duplicate code field.

Field `code` is unique

FactoryBot `sequence` not map with nextval('categories_code_seq').
When I add a test post create new `category`, I get respond error 500. Because `code` is duplicate.
Maybe `nextval('categories_code_seq')` don't increase follow FactoryBot `sequence`.

How can create case test with postgresql sequence field?

Comment: 1. It's `sequence`, not `squence`

Comment: 2. You say "the test is failing", but you didn't show us the test, nor the output.

Comment: 3. You set a `DEFAULT` at the database level. If you want to test the behaviour of this, shouldn't the test be creating a record with `category.code = nil`?

Comment: @TomLord I edited description. `code SET DEFAULT nextval('categories_code_seq');` code start from 1

Comment: So your code creates three database records, right? Have you debugged what exactly is going wrong? What is `category.code`? What is `category_1.code`? What `code` is being set by `Category.create!(from)` in the controller?